# Is it possible to skip license agreement page when splunk starts on first time in docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, containers, dockerfile, splunk

I have created a Dockerfile when the container builds during that time I need to create multiple login users on backside of Splunk.

I am getting splunk agreement issue unable to skip/accept agreement on build container as shown below.

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM splunk/splunk:latest
ENV SPLUNK_HOME /opt/splunk
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
COPY ./splunk-launch.conf /opt/splunk/etc/splunk-launch.conf
COPY ./splunk.license /opt/splunk/etc/licenses/enterprise/splunk.license
COPY ./My-app1 / /opt/splunk/etc/apps/My-app1
COPY ./My-app2 /opt/splunk/etc/apps/My-app2
COPY ./My-app3 /opt/splunk/etc/apps/My-app3
COPY ./splunk_user.sh /opt/splunk/bin/splunk_user.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/splunk/bin/splunk_user.sh
RUN chown -R splunk:splunk /opt/splunk/bin/splunk_user.sh
EXPOSE 8000/tcp 8089/tcp 8191/tcp 9997/tcp 1514 8088/tcp
VOLUME [ “/opt/splunk/etc”, “/opt/splunk/var” ]
WORKDIR /opt/splunk/bin
CMD [“./splunk_user.sh”]
```

---

**splunk_user.sh**

```
./splunk add user pradeep -password passwd123 -role admin -email pradeep@gmail.com -full-name Pradeep -auth admin:changeme
./splunk add user sankar -password passwd123 -role admin -email sankar@gmail.com -full-name Sankar -auth admin:changeme
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [image readme](https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/splunk/), you need to run the image with:

```
-e "SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license"
```

In your Dockerfile, that would be the equivalent of:

```
ENV SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license
```

This flag gets passed to the splunk command in their entrypoint.sh:

```
 sudo -HEu ${SPLUNK_USER} ${SPLUNK_HOME}/bin/splunk start ${SPLUNK_START_ARGS}
```

Comment: Thanks, But now i'm getting this message(  tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
WARNING: error changing terminal modes - password will echo!
Do you agree with this license? [y/n]:  )                                                                            I can't start container its exited state.

Comment: @Rajasekar It's not clear what specifically you changed since there were several options given here. I'd recommend updating your question with what you are currently doing. You also shouldn't be restarting the container, when you make a change to something like the environment, you would delete the old container and start a new one with new settings.

Comment: @BMitch.Yeah Deleted the image and container and re-run the dockerfile with updated one. I faced same issue. Not able to accept license while creating container.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure try this

CMD ["y | ./splunk_user.sh"]